# How can I format page numbering in MS Word which is 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, etc?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

How can I set the page numbers in Microsoft word to have this numbering:

> 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Right-click   a page number and select Toggle Field Codes from the
>   context menu.
>
> You should see something like { PAGE } or { PAGE \ *
>   MERGEFORMAT }. 
>   Change it to

```
{ PAGE \# "00" }
```

> Press F9 to hide the field code and to update the result.

[Source](http://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=7593)

Comment: This helps for `PAGE`, but with a merged document, `{ SECTION }` will give the number of a document in a batch, which may also be helpful.  Also, the `NUMPAGES` doesn't seem to honor the number formatting rules the way that `PAGE` does.  Always returns a number without the leading zeros.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

1. Insert a standard page number
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to show field codes
3. The page number field will show up as either `{ PAGE }` or `{ PAGE \* MERGEFORMAT }` in a grey highlight
4. Replace this with `{ PAGE \# 0# }`
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> again to return to field values

Answer (score 2):

For those who have MacOS, try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.